# How to compile successfully a tagged/marked class with Roslyn

Tags: c#, attributes, roslyn

I'm working on a customer which wants to serialize/deserialize a given object to XML and viceversa. He won't to mark all his classes with attributes ([XmlElement], [XmlArray], etc.) which would be the best solution in my opinion, so he want to generate a dynamic class with the given object, it means, write a new class with the same declared properties and add the attributes for serialization. The new class is writen with a StringBuilder and later it has to be compiled and get a new instance. The problem is that if I write the attributes for serialization, this new class doesn't compile, but if I remove the attributes, the class compiles successfully and I can get an instance.

Here the code

```
dynamicClassCode = @"
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Pat.Infrastructure.Communication.Model
{
   public class RequestMessage_Serializable
   {
      [XmlElement]
      public System.DateTime RequestDateTime { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]  
      public System.String RequestUniqueMessageId { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]  
      public System.Version Version { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]  
      public System.String User { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]  
      public System.String Password { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.String Terminal { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.String Method { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.Object Request { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.String RequestType { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.String EndPointSource { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.String ResponseFormatExpected { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.Object Configuration { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public System.Boolean OneWay { get; set; }
   }
}"
```

and

```cs
string runtimePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\{0}.dll";
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(dynamicClassCode);

IEnumerable<MetadataReference> DefaultReferences = new[] {MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "System.Xml")),
                        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "System.Xml.Serialization")),
                        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
                        };

CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("DynamicCodeManager",
                new[] { syntaxTree },
                DefaultReferences,
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

using (var dllStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdbStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  var emitResult = compilation.Emit(dllStream, pdbStream);
  if (!emitResult.Success)
  {
    var diag = emitResult.Diagnostics;
  }
  else
  {
    dllStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(dllStream.ToArray());
   List<System.Reflection.TypeInfo> typesDeclared = new List<System.Reflection.TypeInfo>(assembly.DefinedTypes);
                    Type type = assembly.GetType(typesDeclared[0].ToString());
                    dynamicObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  }
}
```

The message I get is the following: [0] (7,8): error CS0246: El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'XmlElementAttributeAttribute' no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?) Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSDiagnostic}

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[XmlElementAttribute]` needs to be `[XmlElement]`

Comment: Thanks Markus, I've copied the wrong code... sorry. With [XmlElement] and [XmlArray] it doesn't work. I've just to edit above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to this concrete question:

You need to make sure that all required references are included and that all references come from the same runtime (directory).

This works for me:

```
IEnumerable<MetadataReference> DefaultReferences = new[] {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "mscorlib")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "System.Runtime")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "System.Xml")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "System.Xml.Serialization")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(runtimePath, "System.Xml.XmlSerializer"))
            };
```

Note that the following code you had will most likely load the `mscorlib` assembly from some other directory than 'runtimePath' and thereby load an incompatible assembly.

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
```

Comment: Thanks @NineBerry, it worked for me too. Now tagged class compiles.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your original problem:

First of all, you do not need attributes for serializing classes to XML. The serializer will by default automatically serialize all public properties and fields. You need to use attributes to control the serialization only when you want to deviate from the default behavior.

But then also, you do not need to create dynamic types at runtime to control XML serialization. You can use the `XmlAttributeOverrides` class to simulate a specific type having xml serialization control attributes as explained in the documentation:

[XmlAttributeOverrides Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides)